# Jquery - How to get the input value from a label

Tags: jquery, select, for-loop, label

If I have a bunch of label/selects like:

```
<label for="blah" class="myClass">
<select id="blah" multiple="multiple" size="5">
```

How would I get the value of the selected item based off the label?

So far I have..

```
    $('label[class="myClass"]').each(function(){
        var labelTxt = $(this).text();
        var labelForTxt = $(this).attr('for');
        var inputVal = $('#'+labelForTxt).val();
    });
```

but inputVal isn't the value I expect to see. Instead I get either null/undefined.  Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Comment: do you have any options for the select yet?

Comment: where is input field to get value from..?

Comment: Here is a fiddle with what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/zRjPW/


Please edit it and tell us what do you want if it is not the expected behavior.

Comment: Yep, this is what I have and it works in fiddle.  I'll have to check why it's not working in my real example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

everything is fine, if you hav given close tag for `label` and `select` and options in `select` .check the code , i have modified and implemented.
http://jsfiddle.net/XaMg9/5/

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you are looking for something like this [TEST](http://jsfiddle.net/3Jmuc/2/)

Answer (score 1):

One thing to note. You can use the selector `$('label.myClass')` instead of `$('label[class="myClass"]')`. It's just more standard. That said, if you want the value of each `select` contained within a `label`, do this.

```
$('label.myClass select').each(function(){
    var inputVal = $(this).val();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For multiple select:

```
$("label.myClass select").change(function () {
          var inputval = "";
          $("select option:selected").each(function () {
                inputval += $(this).val() + " ";
              });
          $("div[id='content']").text(inputval);
        });
<div id='content'></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In my use case i was working with mdc(material design) and wanted to untick the checkbox whenever i reopen the checkbox after ticking and cancelling in previous operation.

```
var checkbox = document.querySelector("#checkbox-"+ $(this).val()+ "-label")
```

> var inputId = checkbox.htmlFor

```
var input = document.getElementById(inputId)
input.checked = false;
```